# Can't get JavaScript code to work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I've written a code, on which when the form field reaches its max length (in this example 1) the cursor moves to next field.

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
container.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var target = e.srcElement;
    var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
    var myLength = target.value.length;
    if (myLength >= maxLength) {
        var next = target;
        while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
            if (next == null)
                break;
            if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                next.focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<label><input type="text" name="pin1" maxlength="1" pattern="\d{1}" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required/>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="pin2" maxlength="1" pattern="\d{1}" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required/>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="pin3" maxlength="1" pattern="\d{1}" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required/>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
<input type="text"  name="pin4" maxlength="1" pattern="\d{1}" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required/>
</label>
</div>
```

The form works just fine on Google Chrome and other mobile browsers, but it isn't working on Firefox.

Please help me to get it work on cross browser.

Comment: where is your ``isNumber`` func?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are using the non-standard event property `srcElement`.

```
var target = e.srcElement;
```

From [MDN on Event.srcElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement):

> `Event.srcElement` is a proprietary alias for the standard [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property. It is specific to old versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer.

The only reason it is working in Chrome is this browser currently also aliases this property for compatibility reasons.

Use this instead:

```
var target = e.target;
```

Every version if IE requiring `srcElement` is obsolete, so there is no reason to use this property today.

(I'm assuming you have `isNumber` defined somewhere, else this will also be a problem.)

Comment: yet another example of Chrum backporting Microsoft non-standard rubbish into their browser... Why google, why?

Answer (score 1):

In both Chrome and Firefox, the function isNumber() is not defined.

The other issues is that you're using a non-standard event property srcElement, you should use e.target instead.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement